# How to import json data in D3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

How do I import json file in D3?

I did `d3.json("temp.json");`

But how do I access this data set in further code?

So far I have tried:

```
var data=d3.json("temp.json");
```

But using .data(data) did not work in rest of the code. For example, here

```
var rows = g.selectAll("g.row")
.data(data)
.enter().append("g")
.attr({
  "class": "row",
  "transform": function(d, i) {
    var tx = 170 + i * squareWidth;
    var ty = 150;
    return "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")"
  }
});
```

It is not able to access the data. I copy pasted the json into variable and it worked fine. So there is no problem with the data itself.

Comment: `d3.json('foo.json', function(error, root) {});` root hat the root node of the json.

Answer (score 9):

The function [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) is asynchronous. Thus, you have to wait for the data to be received before reading the `data` variable. This is the reason why, when dealing with asynchronous data, the practice is to do everything inside the `d3.json()` function

```
d3.json("temp.json", function(error, data){
    //use data here
})
// do not use data anymore
```