# How to store a JSON object loaded from a file?

Tags: json, d3.js

I want to store a loaded JSON object in a variable. 
Normally I should do something like:

```
d3.json("jsondatafile.json", function(json){ DO SOMETHING; });
```

But, instead, I want something like:

```
var jsonData = d3.json("jsondatafile.json");
```

I want to access `jsonData` outside the `d3.json` function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can always use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) synchronously:

```
var jsonData;
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "jsondatafile.json",
  async: false
  success: function(data){jsonData = data}
});
```

However it is not recommended as explained in jQuery API:

> The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed. The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating that code execution can continue after the request is made. Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive.

The function [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) is asynchronous. Thus, you have to wait for the data to be received before reading the `data` variable. This is the reason why, when dealing with asynchronous data, the practice is to do everything inside the `d3.json()` function:

```
d3.json("temp.json", function(data){
    //use data here
})
// do not use data anymore
```

Note: answer inspired from my previous answer here: [How to import json data in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074914/how-to-import-json-data-in-d3/16075067#16075067)

Answer (score 5):

According to Interactive Data Vis for the Web by Scott Murray (p 74), you can first declare a global variable. Inside the callback function, assign the data to the global var.

```
var dataset; // global

d3.json("file.json", function(data) {
    dataset = data;
    //any other functions that depend on data
});
```

dataset is avail to all subsequent functions

Comment: A problem I had with this method is that if you try to access `dataset` immediately after the `d3.json` call, it may not all have loaded yet which can lead to errors