# How to update d3 graphics if I load from external data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

So I haven't been able to find an example. I'm loading this huge dataset from an external file with D3, and I'm making some graph with some part of the data. When a slider is moved, I wish make the same graph with some other part of the data.

I used d3.json() for loading the data. The trouble that I'm facing is: since the d3.json() is asynchronous, it loads the dataset for once, and then I can't access it from other functions. I can't have another update function that makes a new graph since I simply can't access the data anymore.

Other people's suggestions have been "only using the data in the d3.json() function: [How to store a JSON object loaded from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455194/how-to-store-a-json-object-loaded-from-a-file)

```
d3.json("temp.json", function(data){
    //use data here
})
// do not use data anymore
```

I tried to use a variable to store the data (the second answer from the same question link above):

```
var DATASET; // global

d3.json("file.json", function(data) {
    DATASET = data;
    //any other functions that depend on data
});

d3.selectAll().data(DATASET).......
```

And I couldn't get it to work at all, since (I assume this is the reason) the data hasn't been loaded to DATASET when the last line of d3.data calls DATASET

Is there any way I could update external data in d3? Should I just load the data again in my update function? Will it affect performance since the dataset is huge?

Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read all the data once, you should store it in your global DATASET variable, just as you show in your code fragment. But instead of placing the update logic in your main script flow, put it inside an `update(...)` function, and call that from the d3.json callback, too... something like this (untested):

```
var DATASET; // global

d3.json("file.json", function(data) {
    // data is loaded, save the full set
    DATASET = data;
    // filter the initial subset
    var subdata = data.filter(...);
    // now update the graph
    updateGraph(subdata);
});

function updateGraph(data) {
    // when invoked without any data, use the full dataset
    var newdata = (data == null ? DATASET : data);

    // data rendering logic starts here...
    d3.selectAll().data(newdata);
  ...
}
```

This saves the full dataset in a global variable, draws the inital graph with a filtered subset of the data, and also allows you to change which data is shown by using a different filter before calling the function again.